# Determine value of series using Euler's identity and geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Use Euler’s Identity and the geometric series to determine the values of the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty r^k \cos(k\theta)$ and $\sum_{k=0}^\infty r^k \sin(k\theta)$, where $|r| < 1$ and $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$.

So, I can *see* the geometric series in the problem in $r^k$, and since $|r| < 1$, it would be a convergent geometric series. I can also *see* Euler's identity with the $\cos(k\theta)$ and $\sin(k\theta)$. I am just not sure how to put it all together. Will I need to somehow combine the sums to get where I want or is there a better, more obvious path that I am not seeing?

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: A start: Find the sum of the geometric series $\sum r^ke^{ik\theta}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ok, so if I did that correctly I got S = $\frac{1}{1-e^{i \theta}}$

Comment: The sum is $\frac{1}{1-re^{i\theta}}$. Now you will need to find the real part of this, for $\sum r^k\cos(k\theta)$, and the imaginary part, for the other sum.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So my real part would be $\frac{-r}{(-r+cos(θ))^2+sin^2(θ)}+\frac{cos(θ)}{(-r+cos(θ))^2+sin^2(θ))}$ and my imaginary part would be $\frac{i sin(θ)}{(-r+cos(θ))^2+sin^2(θ))}$?

Comment: By definition, the imaginary part has no $i$. Also, to get the trigonometric form of the answer, we multiply top and bottom by $1-re^{-i\theta}$. So the top of the real part looks like $1-r\cos(-\theta)$, which is $1-r\cos\theta$. The top of the imaginary part is $r\sin\theta$. For the bottom, I think we get after simplification something like $1-2r\cos\theta+r^2$. That is basically what you got. Now perhaps you might want to write up an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I will do the sum for $\sum_{k \ge 0}r^k\cos(k\theta)$, and the user can try to solve $\sum_{k \ge 0}r^k\sin(k\theta)$ on his own. We note, the real part of $e^{ik\theta}$ is $\cos k\theta$. Hence, if $S=\sum_{k \ge 0}r^k\cos(k\theta)$ then $S$ is the real part of $S'$, where $S'=\sum_{k \ge 0}r^ke^{ik\theta}$. Note, if $w=re^{i\theta}$ then $S'=\sum_{k \ge 0}w^k$. Hence, as $|w|<1$, $S'=\frac{1}{1-re^{i\theta}}$. Thus $S'=\frac{1}{1+r^2-2r\cos \theta}(1-re^{-i\theta})$. Now, the real part of $(1-re^{-i\theta})$ is $1-r\cos \theta$, hence $S=\frac{1}{1+r^2-2r\cos \theta}(1-r\cos \theta)$.

We should check one particular value of $\theta$ to see if our expression is fine. Let $\theta=\frac{1}{2}\pi$, Then $S=\sum_{k\ge 0}(-1)^kr^{2k}$, which is $\frac{1}{1+r^2}$. This agrees with $S=\frac{1}{1+r^2-2r\cos \theta}(1-r\cos \theta)$ (where $\theta$ is replaced by $\frac{1}{2}\pi$).